# Bash скрипт некорректно работает в CRON

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron

Имеется скрипт для автоматизации бэкапа с отправкой примитивной информации на `email`.
Он проверяет, существует ли каталог, в котором надо создать бэкап. Это сетевая папка, которая командой `mount` подключается к машине с бэкапами.

- Если каталог существует, то создаем первую переменную с временной меткой о начале, затем выполняем команду копирования `rsync`, затем создаем вторую перемеренную с временной меткой о конце. Отправляем на почту сообщение о том, когда было начато и закончено копирование.
- Если каталога не существует, то отправляем ошибку.

Тело скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash 
if test -d /home/backupDir/someDir/ 
then 
mess1="$(date +"%y-%m-%d %T") $@ Бэкап начат" 
rsync -auvv /home/backupDir /home/destinationDir
mess2="$(date +"%y-%m-%d %T") $@ Бэкап закончен" 
sendmail email1@mail.ru <<EOF 
subject: Бэкап 
from: server@server.ru 
$mess1 $mess2 
EOF 
else
sendmail email1@mail.ru <<EOF
subject: Бэкап
from: server@gserver.ru
Резервное копирование отменено. Причина: корневой каталог не смонтирован!
EOF
fi
```

При запуске через консоль все прекрасно работает. При запуске через CRON, в `/var/mail/` создается файл `user` с огромным размером, куда записывается весь консольный вывод команды `rsync`. Пробовал давать команду `sendmail` так:

```
echo "$mess1 $mess2" | sendmail email1@mail.ru
```

Результат тот же. Я так понимаю ошибка в потоках ввода\вывода, но разобраться не получается.

Comment: Добавте строку из crontab как вы запускаете скрипт. Пока непонятна  суть вопроса, т.к. работает как и ожидается.

Comment: Я запускаю через Webmin. В сам crontab руками не лазил. Там только стандартные строчки.
`SHELL=/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

Comment: Так а что не нравится, в чём вы видите ошибку?

Comment: Когда запускаешь руками - все работает. 
Когда запускает задачу сам Cron по расписанию - email не приходит, а вместо этого создается огромный файл в `/var/mail/` . Коллега ниже уже объяснил почему это происходит. Сейчас протестирую.

Comment: Коллега ниже это Ваш покорный слуга. Попробуйте.

Comment: Я до ужаса невнимателен!  =)
Спасибо за подсказку! теперь работает как надо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron всегда пытается послать все потоки вывода во время выполнения команд на email. Выдержка из [мануала CRON](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/cron.8.html):

> When executing commands, any output is  mailed  to  the  owner  of  the
>    crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in the
>    crontab, if such exists).

Для того, чтобы избежать рассылки вывода комманды на email, все потоки вывода надо перенаправить в файл или на `/dev/null`, если вывод вообще не нужен.

```
30 * * * * scriptname &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Премного благодарен! Попробуем!

Comment: Если действительно только это ваша проблема, то  можете не пробовать, т.к испробовано 1000 раз.

Comment: Можно чуть более короткий вариант использовать: `&>/dev/null` вместо `>/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @MaxU Можно конечно, спасибо.